# Combine three fields from form and validate uniqueness in table with two coumns in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am having a products create form, in that form, I am having `product_name`, `product_quantity` and `product_weight`.

These three fields that has to be inserted in `products` table. 
In products table I kept two fields to save these three fields i.e product name and product quantity(in which I am saving product quantity and product weight). I have shown an example of my query

Suppose in  form user enters  Dove 250 gm(These are three fields that will be come from that form)
in data base i am saving them as like dove(in one field) 250 gm(in another field i.e product quantity).
now i want, when creating a form a product with same name Dove 250 gm should be inserted again,
for this I want a validation with uniquness, can anyone help me regarding this

At present I kept the validation as shown below

```
 'name' => 'required|max:240|unique:products,name,NULL,product_quantity',
```

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried a custom validation rule? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: No i didnt tried,  i will check once tq